# Maximum values along axis of Numpy ndarray?

Tags: numpy, max, multidimensional-array

[image: numpy_array]

I'm afraid that I can't describe the problem so I draw a sketch of it.Anyway,what I need is to find the max values along the 0th axis in a numpy ndarray,i.e.array.shape(5,5,3), and their corresponding "layer numbers", and use the "layer numbers" to create a new 2d array with shape of (1,5,3).Hope I'm giving a clear description here..thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the documentation of `np.max`, you'll see it takes an `axis` argument:

```
a.max(axis=0)
```

But that won't help you yet. However, there's a function `argmax` that gives you the indices of the maxima along a given axis:

```
a.argmax(axis=...)
```

So, let's find your first (5,5) array: it's `a[...,0]`. You can find the position of the maxima per rows (or columns) with `a[...,0].max(axis=1)` (or 0), and use that to find the values on the other sides.

Comment: And how can I get the "layer numbers" of the max values?

Comment: Thanks!Actually the argmax(axis=0) returns the array I need