# numpy find maximum digit in array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape `(1, 7, 3)` i would like to find the row with highest element in the 3 column. Eg.: 232 is the biggest in the 3rd column so it should output `[196 228 232]` How can I do it? I tried np.argmax but failed

Here is an example array:

```
[[[218 204 204]
[344 194  31]
[284 140 108]
[196 228 232]
[324 196  28]
[224 228  57]
[174 250 144]]]
```

Comment: maybe this link might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403238/maximum-values-along-axis-of-numpy-ndarray

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximum values along axis of Numpy ndarray?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403238/maximum-values-along-axis-of-numpy-ndarray)

Comment: a.max(axis=2) returns `[218 344 284 232 324 228 250]` which is max value of each row and i need element with largest row[2] element as in question

Comment: Highest digit (e.g. 9) or value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argmax` is the right idea  here. let's do it step by step.

```
 row_nr = np.argmax(data[0, :, 2])
```

this selects the third column and finds the index of the largest value.
it remains to select this row:

```
data[0, row_nr, :]
```

Comment: thank you for taking time to read and answer my question. It makes perfect sense now